# Show an item in context menu only when it clicked on an image in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

[UPDATE] I may have explained the issue wrong: I know how to hide the menu element - but how to test if the clicked element is editable? Chrome detects an editable element - how to achieve it in ff.

I'm trying to get my item in a the context menu to be shown only when it was clicked on an image

this is my `emailpicture.js`

code:

```
function showHideItems(event)
{   
      var show = document.getElementById("emailImage");
      show.hidden = !(gContextMenu.onImage);
}
```

and the xul code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<overlay id="emailpicture" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://emailpicture/content/emailpicture.js"/>

<menupopup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
  <menuitem id="emailImage" label="Email This Image" onpopupshowing="showHideItems()" oncommand=""/>

</menupopup>


</overlay>
```

the result of this is showing on every object in the browser a bunch of items(might be all the items of FireFox)
should i use the `onpopupshowing` event? or another one?
am i using it right?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Take a look at the [MDN page for context menus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/PopupGuide/ContextMenus#Hiding_and_Showing_Menu_Items_based_on_Context), "Hiding and Showing Menu Items based on Context" and "Determining what was Context Clicked". And remember you can apply DOM methods to a `<menupopup>`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, this code is taken straight from there. I think, that my problem is in the place where i call the function, in the xl file. any suggestions ?

Comment: Oh, yes, the event should be on the `<menupopup>`, not the `<menuitem>`. Attach the event to #contentAreaContextMenu (do it by JavaScript's `addEventListener` if you're not sure if setting the attribute will cause a conflict with another event listener)

Comment: Ok, thanks again. What I'm still missing is how to add the `eventListener` - what it should include and where to add it. Can I do it from the xul file?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at [the ContextMenu MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/PopupGuide/ContextMenus#Hiding_and_Showing_Menu_Items_based_on_Context) they have an example of just this. The main issue with your current code is that you've put *onpopupshowing* on the `<menuitem>` when it should be on `<menupopup>`. Furthermore, if you look at the MDN for [`document.popupNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.popupNode) it says you're encouraged to use [`.triggerNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Property/triggerNode) instead. Additionally, looking at the [popupshowing event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/popupshowing) we see it has a `.target`, but it isn't clear whether this is the `<menupopup>` (I assumed this below), the node that was clicked or something else (see comment in code).

The following code makes use of the above and attaches the listener using [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) to make sure there isn't a conflict with anything else that might use the *onpopupshowing* attribute.

In your *emailpicture.js*

```
// First define listener
function showHideItems(e) {
    var menupopup = e.target, // I believe `.target` is the <menupopup>, otherwise use `this`. 
        triggerNode = menupopup.triggerNode, // get node that was clicked to open context menu
        triggerIsImage = (triggerNode instanceof Components.interfaces.nsIImageLoadingContent && triggerNode.currentURI),
          // test if it is an image (as from MDN, I would've gone with `.nodeType` and `.nodeName` checks?)
        elmToHide = menupopup.getElementById('emailImage');
    if(elmToHide)
        elmToHide.hidden = !triggerIsImage;
}
// Then attach it to <menupopup>, remember the element has to exist before you can do this so you might want to wait for DOMContentLoaded
document.getElementById('contentAreaContextMenu')
    .addEventListener('popupshowing', showHideItems, false);
```

Then for the XUL don't include the attribute *onpopupshowing*.

I'll point out that I've not tested this so if it isn't working, first check the even is fired then check `.target` is as I assumed (and possibly clarify MDN for others in future).

Comment: If there is anything in my answer that needs corrections please comment again so I can edit it, and if it was helpful please up-vote/accept it. Thanks.